# complicated Ms Access SQL count

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to count the numbers in column B as long as all of them have a yes next to them, but i need to count only those yes's for which all numbers from column A have a yes.

I would not count the numbers from column B, as one of them has a no. So that makes 2 yes and one no for the A1. But if it was a yes, that would make all of the A1 yes, so I would like to count the numbers from column B.

This is the count I am using from a previous question:

```
SELECT Table1.ColumnA
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.ColumnA
HAVING (((Sum(IIf([ColumnC]='No',1,0)))=0));
```

I thoughed that it would count non-distinct values, but it doesnt.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxf6V.jpg)

Comment: Please, Can you provide a sample from your data? I think will be more clearly

Comment: Providing a sample or an example of similar data would be very helpful.

Comment: Basically, if everything belonging to A1 in column A is a yes, i need to count the items in column B, which belong to A1. My query counts the items from column A, but A1 has several items belonging to it from column B, so I would need to count them.

Answer (score 0):

select columnA, sum(iif(columnB="Yes",1,0)) as Count from Table1 group by ColumnA

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMNA = 'YES' AND COLUMNB = 'YES'
```

This should work as i get from your first two lines.